# I have an application where I have loaded an image on google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, indoor-positioning-system

I am creating an application in android used for indoor mapping, where I have loaded an image of building floor plan on google Maps using GroundOverlay.
When the user taps on image, I need to capture the X,Y coordinates of the image.
I can do this by doing some Math using Latitudes and Longitudes. But as it as indoor application I cannot depend on lat and long.

Could you please suggest any other approach to get the XY coordinates of the building when the user taps on it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a transformation formula between the latlong you will get from google maps and your building's internal coordinates, or the other way around - map points of interest in your building to latlong, and then use google. 
The adjustment between your building locations and latlong is called geo referencing, and it can be done using 2 points on the map
Hope this helps